# Insert YouTube player with JQuery HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I'm almost done with my mini-project which I have put a lot of work into! The only thing is now that I need to put a Youtube link player into the HTML and I don't really now how to start.

So what I'm doing is that I take information from my API where its already have a YouTube link ready for example https://youtu.be/Mh2ebPxhoLs and now I need it to be shown in my HTML as a YouTube player. Only problem I don't really know how to start it.

This is how my site looks right now:

[image: My site]

As you see there is a YouTube trailer link at the bottom which I haven't got to that "level" yet and need your help for it!

Basically its a trailer from the movie I'm searching for and I want it to be under the poster, somewhere there but I can do it by myself. Only problem is now I just need to know how to make a YouTube player to understand the YouTube link.

Right now I'm using in my HTML a

```
<div id="trailer"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#trailer').html("Trailer: " + data.trailer);
```

and I have no CSS for the trailer yet.

So I just want to know, how can I make the link understand and fill my HTML with the YouTube player?

Comment: I assume you want to embed a video; `<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Yes something like that, but only that in the src i want it to be linked my link which is in my api, if you understand what i mean?

Comment: Go to any video on YouTube, and somewhere it'll give the option to get its 'embed' code/HTML. Just update your JS to add that code to your `#trailer` div — but dynamically use the YouTube ID from your `data.trailer` instead of the one YouTube included in its embed code.

Comment: @WeInThis are the movies + trailer links pulled from a database or do you add them yourself trough html?

Comment: I have a API which gives the results back as a JSON, in the json I have the link so by the link I was thinking to get it into a embed youtube.

Comment: @WeInThis Check out my answer

Comment: Hi there. I've reverted the major edit to this question - removing questions by overwriting them with nonsense is regarded as wilful vandalisation and is treated quite seriously by moderators. If you are not able to share the relevant part of your code, then Stack Overflow is not a suitable site. Downvoted, with regrets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you want to get the `id` from the link and use that to fill the html with the youtube `iframe`. You can do this by using `replace`.

```
var videoId = data.trailer.replace("https://youtu.be/", ""); //Leaves just the id
$('#trailer').html("Trailer: <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>");
```

Comment: I will try that in a minute. I will come back if something :)

Comment: @WeInThis if this solved your problem, please mark this answer as the Accepted answer

Comment: It worked! I did it as ´$('#trailer').html("Trailer: <iframe width='420' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + data.trailer + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>");`` and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Take an iframe for HTML

```
<iframe id="videoArea" width="350" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/X0DeIqJm4vM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then with your links you can create a property mapper to the iframe:

```
$('#videoArea').prop("src", data.trailer);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tive/J6WQm/)**